# ionic css issue while set ion-icon at bottom right to image

Tags: html, css, ionic2, ionic3

i want to achieve below layout in my ionic app

[image]

so below is my code

**html code**

```
<div class="common_padding">
<ion-item text-center class="imagebg" no-padding (click)="openCameraActionSheet()">
  <img class="circle-pic" src="{{client.logo}}" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" />
  <ion-icon name="star" item-right></ion-icon>

</ion-item>
```

css code

```
page-profile {

  .imagebg{
      background: map-get($colors,primary);
      color: map-get($colors,whiteColor);
  }
  .common_padding{
    padding: 0;


   }
   .circle-pic{
      width:50px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }

 }
```

And when i run above code i get output as below

[image]

it display right end of view i need it near to image any idea how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html file

```
<div class="common_padding">
<ion-item text-center class="imagebg" no-padding (click)="openCameraActionSheet()">
  <div class="profile-image">
  <img class="circle-pic" src="{{client.logo}}" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" />
  <ion-icon name="star" item-right></ion-icon>
  </div>
</ion-item>
</div>
```

css file

```
 .profile-image{
         margin:0px auto;
    }
```

i hope its work for you.

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya if this answer fixed the issue, please mark it as accepted so we can close the question. Thanks.